# How to make multiple fields $min properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have the following Collection:

```
{
  TariffId: 0101H01,
  RoomId: 01H01,
  HotelId: H01,
  Price: 180,
  ...       //other fields
},
{
  TariffId: 0201H01,
  RoomId: 01H01,
  HotelId: H01,
  Price: 120
}
{ 
  TariffId: 0301H01,
  RoomId: 02H01,
  HotelId: H01,
  Price: 100
  ...       //other fields
}
```

I want to output the minimum Price for each HotelId and know exactly which RoomId and TariffId it relates to as well all other fields. The result should be:

```
{ 
  TariffId: 0201H01,
  RoomId: 01H01,
  HotelId: H01,
  Price: 120
}
{ 
  TariffId: 0301H01,
  RoomId: 02H01,
  HotelId: H01,
  Price: 100
  ...       //other fields
}
```

I have tried:

```
 db.collection.aggregate{
      {$group: {_id :{ RoomId: "$RoomId", tariffId: "$_id"} , HotelId:{$first: "$HotelId"} , Price: {$min: "$Price" }}},
      {$group: {_id : "$HotelId", RoomId: {$first:"$RoomId"}, tariffId: {$first: "$_id"} , Price: {$min: "$Price" }}}
      }
```

But then the result is not correct. The first wrongly assign tariffIdm0101H01 to the min price: 120. this is what I get:

```
{ 
  TariffId: 0101H01,
  RoomId: 01H01,
  HotelId: H01,
  Price: 100
  ...       //other fields
}
```

and it should have been:

```
{ 
  TariffId: 0301H01,
  RoomId: 02H01,
  HotelId: H01,
  Price: 100
  ...       //other fields
}
```

How do I make this query works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

The reason you are getting a wrong price is because you are using two separate operators (`$min` and `$first`) and they are not synchronized with each other. `$min` is returning the minimum price in the whole collection and `$first` is getting the first document from the whole collection.

**Solution**

What you want to do is sort (make sure to have an index) and then group and use the `$first` operator. Since we are sorting before grouping the first document will be the one with the minimum price.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // important sort by price before grouping
    {
        $sort: { Price: 1 }
    },
    // group by hotel and room ID and get the first document
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {                
                HotelId: '$HotelId',
                RoomId: "$RoomId",
            },
            doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' }
        }
    },
    // (optional) replace the root document
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$doc' }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @leonziyo ! It worked li a charm! VERY CLEVER to not use $min in this case and still get the min value by means of sorting and getting $first answer. I only had to take out RoomId from the grouping and it found the minimum value for each Hotel. As I have a Mongodb < version 3.4 I also changed to $project in order to return my collection at root.